# Message Sent To Deallocated Instance Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, dealloc

I am getting a crash saying `*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7021e80` in my dealloc method for line `[muscleURL release];`

The init for `muscleURL` is `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *muscleURL;`

This only happens when I click the done button in my NavBar.  Here is the related code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem * doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];
    [doneButton release];
}

-(void)dismissView
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] -3)] animated:YES];
}
```

Edit:

In the parent view, parent view's `muscleURL` is init like this

```
-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath
{
    NSString *muscleURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
    detailViewController.muscleURL = muscleURL;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize `muscleURL`?

Comment: In the parent view's didSelectRowAtIndex method, I have detailViewController.muscleURL = self.muscleURL.

Comment: .... also the code where you call [muscleURL release] and probably you're dealloc method. The error you're seeing is most likely cause by unbalanced retain-release call of muscleURL.

Comment: Then how is the "muscleURL" in the parent view being initialized?

Comment: I added the code to the question. Thanks.

Comment: That code seems fine. You must be over-releasing that string somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSString *muscleURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
```

This returns an auto released object so you do not need to release it in your dealloc method as the system has already deallocated the memory. It might be a good idea for you to read up on Objective-C memory management, there is a document on the Apple Developer website.

Comment: I am not releasing that string.  That string is init in the didSelectRowAtIndex method in the parentView.  The `muscleURL` I am releasing in dealloc is the one in the childView where it is an ivariable.

Comment: as it turns out, I did have a [muscleURL release] for that NSString at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which I removed.  No more crash!

Comment: While this led to the answer, the statement that `you do not need to release it in your dealloc` is wrong since it'll be retained by the assignment through the property.   The extraneous release in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method was the problem.

Comment: I apologize when he said that it happened in his dealloc method, he didn't say in which controller and so to me it seemed as if it was being released in the parent dealloc method, it's the detail view controller's responsibility to release the object once it's been passed through property. While my answer isn't correct, I hope you understand why I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIBarButtonItem * doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView)]autorelease]; 
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];

}

-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath
{
NSString *tempURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
detailViewController.muscleURL = tempURL;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to use `[doneButton release];` and what is the difference from my code?  You just changed the NSString name from `muscleURL` to temp URL`?